# How to make sure the function turns what I write into a string

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
abc = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'secondstring', 'thirdstring']

def findletter(letter, l1st, idx):

    if letter in l1st[idx]:
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")

findletter("i", abc, 0)
```

This works, however I have a few questions:

1. Why writing the letter the 'i' without quotation marks gives an error?
2. How do I make so it'd take letters without quotation marks?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want it to take letters without quotation marks?

Answer (score 3):

A "letters without quotation marks" would be a variable.

If you set that variable to a string first, it will work without errors.

```
i = "something"
findletter(i, abc, 0)
```

Otherwise it's un undeclared variable, which is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Writing i without quotations considers it as a variable which i has not been assigned to
For the second, str(abc) would work as str() converts what you have to a string

Answer (score 0):

If you write "i" without the quotation marks, it will take it as a variable instead of a string.
If you do not want to hard-code what you to search, try this:

```
abc = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'secondstring', 'thirdstring']

def findletter(letter, l1st, idx):

    if letter in l1st[idx]:
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")

i = input("Enter the string to be searched: ")
findletter(i, abc, 0)
```

This will ask you what to search in the shell, every time you run the code and `input()` function always returns the value as a string.